# Google app Id find application ID

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a long time application created with GAE api for Python . 
Unfortunately I have lost the source code and I tried to retrieve it using this command:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <app-id> <path>
```

As the app-id I just wrote the first part of the address, for example if I have myApp22.appspot.com - I wrote myApp22. However the script output is "This application does not exist" . I believe it expects a real application ID as explained here: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_appid_version
But I don't have access to my source file. Is there any other way that I can find out my application ID?

Very appreciated.

Comment: just tried it and it worked fine for me. to eliminate any auth issues, you may with to append the --no_cookies flag -> appcfg.py download_app -A <app-id> <path> --no_cookies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the username and login for your Google account, you can go to appengine.google.com and go to "Application Settings". The App ID is listed there as "Application Identifier".

Comment: I am right there, I just saw my application identifier is identical to what I have been giving as parameter. But it does not work.

Comment: And it finally worked,, I had to use the parameter --no_cookies , because at first time I input another email address which was not the address I registered the application for. Thank you. I figured it out alone but maybe it will help somebody in the future.

Comment: Apparently that is old and no longer available.  The dashboard has changed and settings does not display the Application Identifier.  It has a project ID, but that is not helpful.  Do you have an answer that works in 2016?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the top right corner on the dashboard.

#### {APPLICATION-ID}.appspot.com

Comment: isn't it the project id?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed the ID of the base app_engine_application which was just the name of the PROJECT-ID.

So in case none of the above work, give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the application id is the project id prefixed with `s~`.  Not sure if that is a universal convention or not.  So if your app is `PROJECT-ID.appspot.com`, try `s~PROJECT-ID`.