# What is "App ID" in Google Cloud Integration Connectors?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform

Im trying to create a new API connection in Google Cloud, one of the required fields is `App ID`. Can someone help me understand what the app id should be? No matter what try i'm getting error `'appid' is not a valid connection property.`

In context here in the a screenshot: [image]

I have tried:

- the GCP project id
- the application name in Shopify (the API i'm connecting to)
- making up a name
- the Shopify ClientID (the counterpart to the Client Secret)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who has an account with google cloud has a unique "AppID". This is used to identify every user using this ID. You can find yours on your profile. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the error 'appid' is not a valid connection property, it means that you are trying to connect to a server that does not accept the App ID as a valid authentication method. To resolve this issue, you can try one of the following solutions:

- If the server is using an app ID, ensure that you are using the
  correct app ID and that the app ID is configured correctly. The app
  id is the GCP project number, the numerical project number, not the
  project id.  This is seen in the console dashboard.
- Use a different authentication method (e.g. username and password,
  OAuth, etc.).
- Check the server's settings to ensure that the App ID is enabled as
  an authentication method.

Refer to this [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037323/), [SO2](https://serverfault.com/questions/808484/) for how to find the APP ID

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply, it's not this id though, i tried it. It only really makes sense for it to be the Admin App ID for the Shopify API app. Although this doesn't work either. im giving up and going to write a regular API script :(

Comment: You have to go from your partner dashboard on the app you are searching for the API Client ID for, then in the URL you will see something like: --> https://partners.shopify.com/1331131/apps/1234567
The API Client ID is the last number in the URL so in this case 1234567

Comment: Or else Can you refer this [google doc](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/connectors/shopify/configure) on shopify integration and also You can post your questions and discuss this connector in the Google Cloud community at [Cloud Forums](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Integration-Services/bd-p/cloud-integration-services).